# Сможет ли curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false); на сайте с https для парсера обойти бан?

Tags: php

Есть PHP парсер, который использует Curl. Он парсит изображения из сайта https://www.airliners.net. Где-то прочитал, что если для curl-соединения прописать `curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, false)` и `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false)`, и у сайта будет протокол https, то это поможет обойти бан из-за постоянного парсинга. Правда ли это?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

вряд ли, т.к система все равно будет видеть и отслеживать кол-во запросов исходящих с твоего адреса. 100% Обход, это использование прокси, а это уже другой разговор.

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 1):

Конечно нет, эта опция для игнорирование проверки сертификата SSL. Т.е. сайт может иметь просроченный сертификат.

Для обхода банов нужны proxy и возможно полностью эмулировать поведение обычного пользователя, например через puppeteer